# Adding modules to app request variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been following a NodeJs tutorial, and the author adds modules to the `req` variable in the `app.use()` callback like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   req.date = date;
   next();
});
```

In this case, `date` is a 'module' I created and then required:

```
var date = require('./date.js');
```

So then in, for instance, `index.js`, I can access the functions in my `date` module like this:

```
var date = req.date;
var currentDate = date.getDate() //getDate is a function in my 'date' module
```

Now this works fine, but as I'm new to Node I don't know if this is the recommended or best way to access modules in my routes. My concern is this seems kind of messy, adding modules manually to the `req` variable.

So my question is; What is the recommended way to use modules in NodeJs in other JS files other than `app.js`?

Comment: Just `require()` them in the files where you need them.

Comment: Oh... wow. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot about the `require` function in 'external' JS files. For instance, in `index.js` (taken from my question):

```
var date = require('date');
var currentDate = date.getDate();
```

The `date.js` file is placed into my `node_modules` directory, where NodeJs will look for it.

Comment: You need to use a relative path (`require('./date')`).

Comment: @robertklep I tried that, still throwing the error about not being able to find the module. The module is in the root of the project, and my `index.js` file is in my `routes` folder which is right off the root, would that affect anything?

Comment: I figured it out, I just placed the `date.js` file into my `node_modules` directory.